# How to ignore CSS img styling for certain sections of the website?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I need some help, with a jquery snippet preferably. The snippet we are looking for would be something, that would allow us to ignore certain css classes in the same page.

EX) We have the Header logo img and we would like to ignore the css styling of img, how can this be achieve?

Css

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

We would like to ignore the css style for our first img and leave the style for the second img, which is the best approach?

Comment: Use a class - `<img /> <img class="style">` | `.style { /*style*/ }`...

Comment: Use CSS selectors e.g.: `.nav > img , .header > .left > img ` etc. It will set scope of applying CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like :-

```
img:not(:first-child){
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu4ovgwr/)

Comment: you would probably want to add an id and class to the header logo image as mentioned above rather than using :first-child as for some reason he wants a jquery snippet to do this so I assume he wants to add/remove the css on the logo for some reason. So you could use something like

<img id="header_logo" src="" />
$('#header_logo').addClass('.header_logo);

and then in change your css above to be img:not(.header_logo){

Comment: @naw103 he didn't provide the html. i have just give him an idea how he can apply the css to image exept first image it doesn't matter it have an id or not.

Comment: he can use selecter according to his requirement

Answer (score 0):

Give your header logo image a id or class and use the `:not` selector of css . Like

```
:not(selector) {
    css declarations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS states that all instances of `<img>` will have the style applied.

You can use a class selector for the purpose of the styling instead of the general selector, to avoid the inclusion of the first image.